# Unable to simultaneously initialize Docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts and configure PostgreSQL with arguments using PersistentVolume in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pvc

Currently, I have a task to set up a PostgreSQL 14 cluster consisting of one master and two standby replicas in Kubernetes. I'm using NFS PersistentVolumes with the CSI driver as the storage for the database. The volume with the database data is mounted at /var/lib/postgresql/data/db/data/ (PG_DATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/db/data/).

During the setup of the master database, I encountered an issue: when starting the container, I cannot simultaneously initialize the .sql scripts in the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ directory and override the container parameters with arguments specifying the path to postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf (postgres -c "/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf" -c "/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf").

If I initialize the database without arguments, the database and users are successfully created, but an empty postgresql.conf configuration is applied, which is created in the /var/lib/postgresql/data/db/data/ directory. If I use arguments to set the correct configuration, the database and users are not initialized.

I understand that the database can be started with arguments, and then manually go into the pod and create everything you need, but this approach is very undesirable in my case, because I make a kustomize chart out of it all.

How can I solve this issue of initializing the database and configuring PostgreSQL using PersistentVolume in Kubernetes? I would appreciate any advice and suggestions.

I tried several solutions:

1. Build a custom PostgreSQL image with an additional initialization script entrypoint.sh and run it with the necessary tools.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Perform any pre-initialization tasks here (if needed)
# Run the PostgreSQL initialization scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
docker-entrypoint.sh postgres &

# Wait for PostgreSQL to start
until pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
do
  echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL to start..."
  sleep 1
done

# Execute the provided command with the additional arguments
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:14-bullseye

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["postgres"]
```

However, this option results in the error: *"lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists: Another critical error indicating that there is a lock file (postmaster.pid) that already exists, suggesting that another postmaster process might be running."*

2. Create an additional container (I'm currently considering this option) where the files postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf, and init.sql, are placed in the directories /etc/postgresql/ and /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/, respectively. My idea was to use an initialization container to prepare the environment and run the initialization script, and then launch the main container with the necessary arguments. Both containers should use the same PVC named "db-nfs-pvc".
   However, this option also doesn't work due to the error: *"pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims".*

Dockerfile (this is what I'm using now):

```
FROM postgres:14-bullseye

COPY pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
COPY postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

3. Attempt to place a script in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ that would configure everything at once:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb;"
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER myuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypassword';"
psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;"
exec postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf -c hba_config=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:14-bullseye

COPY initdb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sh
```

However, this script doesn't execute at all.

Here is the full code of deployment.yaml manifest of master db:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: deployment
        app: db
    spec:
      affinity:
       nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: affinity-type
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - postgres
      tolerations:
        - key: "key"
          value: "database"
          operator: "Equal"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      volumes:
        - name: db-nfs-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-nfs-pvc
              #- name: init-volume
              #configMap:
              #name: db-init
              #- name: db-hba-conf
              #configMap:
              #name: hba-init
              #- name: db-postgresql-conf
              #configMap:
              #name: postgresql-conf-init
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres-master:v1.0.2 #CUSTOM IMAGE OF postgres:14-bullseye
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db-nfs-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
                # subPath: db/data

                #- name: init-volume
                #mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
                #- name: db-postgresql-conf
                #mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
                #subPath: postgresql.conf
                #- name: db-hba-conf
                #mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
                #subPath: pg_hba.conf
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
            - "-c"
            - "hba_file=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf"
      initContainers:
        - name: init-db
          image: postgres-master:v1.0.2 #CUSTOM IMAGE OF postgres:14-bullseye
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db-nfs-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              #subPath: db/data
```

Option without init container, in which db-init scripts are not initialized:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: deployment
        app: db
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: affinity-type
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - postgres
      tolerations:
        - key: "key"
          value: "database"
          operator: "Equal"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      volumes:
        - name: db-nfs-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-nfs-pvc
        - name: init-volume
          configMap:
            name: db-init
        - name: db-hba-conf
          configMap:
            name: hba-init
        - name: db-postgresql-conf
          configMap:
            name: postgresql-conf-init
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres:14-bullseye
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db-nfs-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: db/data
            - name: init-volume
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - name: db-postgresql-conf
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
              subPath: postgresql.confvi
            - name: db-hba-conf
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
              subPath: pg_hba.conf
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "config_file=/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf"
            - "-c"
            - "hba_file=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do things the `postgres` image should do on its own.  You shouldn't need to separately start the database, for example.  Do you have an example that uses the unmodified `postgres` image, without an init container or custom entrypoint script?  What is the name of the initialization script?  What shows up in `kubectl logs` when you run it?